# Is it possible to test my apps made with flutter using my android device?

Tags: android, flutter, bios

I am currently a new  app developer and currently i am facing a problem. I am not able to turn on bios on my system were the VT-X technology is disabled. So i just wanted to know is it possible to test my app build with flutter directly on my mobile without enabling VT-X from bios?

Comment: VT-x is for running the emulator smoothly. If you have device, you can build on PC (assuming SDK supports your OS version) and deploy to device without VT-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, Just go to settings search for **developer options** and then enable it, if you don't get that then go to your **phone info/details** and scrol to the bottom and just **tap on the build number 7 times** and a toast will show that dev mode is enabled. **Then just connect your device and run your project!**

If you don't get any of these then connect your usb first and then click on the notification which says usb connected then change the option from charging to enable debug mode. Make sure you allow your computer when a dialog box appears after that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should enable developer Option on the  phone and then turn on USB debugging.
then connect your device to your pc and run your flutter app on it.